# Can you think of a set $A$ for which $A \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's an exercise from Velleman's How to Prove It. I can only think of the empty set ($A=\emptyset$), but we're asked to think of another, if there is such a set $A$.

Edit: $\mathcal{P}(A)$ being, of course, the powerset of $A$.

Comment: Shubham Johri has already answered your question, but, for reference, such a set is called a [transitive set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set); this is a set $A$ such that every element of $A$ is also a subset of $A$. (this is precisely the condition you've written.) these sets turn out to be very important and useful in set theory, as they are particularly "well-behaved" in certain desirable ways

Comment: What is the question?  The power set of $A$ contains all the subsets of $A$, including $A$, so every set $A$ is contained in the power set.

Comment: @mjw that is not correct. consider the set $A=\{\{\emptyset\}\}$. written differently, let $B=\{\emptyset\}$, and let $A=\{B\}$. then $B\in A$, but $B$ is not a subset of $A$, since $\emptyset\notin A$. thus $B\notin \mathcal{P}(A)$ and so $A$ is not a subset of $\mathcal{P}(A)$. what you have shown is that $A$ is an _element_ of $\mathcal{P}(A)$, but not that $A$ is a _subset_ of $\mathcal{P}(A)$. this is an important distinction; see eg the wikipedia article I linked to in the comment above yours

Comment: @mjw The question requires $A$ to be a **subset** of $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: Okay.  Thank you for the clarification.  Glad I asked.

Comment: @mjw no worries, my pleasure! :)

Comment: In the latest (3rd) edition of How To Prove It, this is exercise 5 in Section 3.3.  Take a look at exercise 4.  It gives you a way of using one solution (such as $A = \emptyset$) to generate another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\{\emptyset\}$ or $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ or $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ and so on.

Comment: What about the case $A$ is not a family of sets?

Comment: @jpcoli Since $A$ is required to be a subset of its power set which is by definition a family of sets, $A$ must be a family of sets or empty.

Comment: Thanks! It makes perfect sense.